# Flutter: How to read file from assets, asynchronously, without blocking the UI

Tags: asynchronous, file-io, dart, flutter

In flutter, `rootBundle.load()` gives me a `ByteData` object.

What exactly is a `ByteData` object in dart? Can It be used to read files asynchronously?

I don't really understand the motive behind this.

Why not just give me a good ol' `File` object, or better yet the full path of the asset?

In my case, I want to read bytes from an asset file asynchronously, byte by byte and write to a new file. (to build an XOR decryption thingy that doesn't hang up the UI)

This is the best I could do, and it miserably hangs up the UI.

```
loadEncryptedPdf(fileName, secretKey, cacheDir) async {
  final lenSecretKey = secretKey.length;

  final encryptedByteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$fileName');

  final outputFilePath = cacheDir + '/' + fileName;
  final outputFile = File(outputFilePath);

  if (!await outputFile.exists()) {
    Stream decrypter() async* {
      // read bits from encryptedByteData, and stream the xor inverted bits

      for (var index = 0; index < encryptedByteData.lengthInBytes; index++)
        yield encryptedByteData.getUint8(index) ^
        secretKey.codeUnitAt(index % lenSecretKey);
      print('done!');
    }

    print('decrypting $fileName using $secretKey ..');
    await outputFile.openWrite(encoding: AsciiCodec()).addStream(decrypter());
    print('finished');
  }

  return outputFilePath;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, while the answers posted by @Jonah Williams and  @Richard Heap don't suffice on their own, I tried a combination of both, and it works good for me.

Here is a complete solution -

uses path_provider package to get the cache directory

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

// Holds a Future to a temporary cache directory
final cacheDirFuture =
    (() async => (await (await getTemporaryDirectory()).createTemp()).path)();

_xorDecryptIsolate(args) {
  Uint8List pdfBytes = args[0].buffer.asUint8List();
  String secretKey = args[1];
  File outputFile = args[2];

  int lenSecretKey = secretKey.length;

  for (int i = 0; i < pdfBytes.length; i++)
    pdfBytes[i] ^= secretKey.codeUnitAt(i % lenSecretKey);

  outputFile.writeAsBytesSync(pdfBytes, flush: true);

}


/// decrypt a file from assets using XOR,
/// and return the path to a cached-temporary decrypted file.
xorDecryptFromAssets(String assetFileName, String secretKey) async {
  final pdfBytesData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$assetFileName');
  final outputFilePath = (await pdfCacheDirFuture) + '/' + assetFileName;
  final outputFile = File(outputFilePath);

  if ((await outputFile.stat()).size > 0) {
    print('decrypting $assetFileName using $secretKey ..');
    await compute(_xorDecryptIsolate, [pdfBytesData, secretKey, outputFile]);
    print('done!');
  }

  return outputFilePath;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Dart a `ByteData` is similar to a Java `ByteBuffer`. It wraps a byte array, providing getter and setter functions for 1, 2 and 4 byte integers (both endians).

Since you want to manipulate bytes it's easiest to just work on the underlying byte array (a Dart `Uint8List`). `RootBundle.load()` will have already read the whole asset into memory, so change it in memory and write it out.

```
Future<String> loadEncryptedPdf(
    String fileName, String secretKey, String cacheDir) async {
  final lenSecretKey = secretKey.length;

  final encryptedByteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$fileName');

  String path = cacheDir + '/' + fileName;
  final outputFile = File(path);

  if (!await outputFile.exists()) {
    print('decrypting $fileName using $secretKey ..');

    Uint8List bytes = encryptedByteData.buffer.asUint8List();
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
      bytes[i] ^= secretKey.codeUnitAt(i % lenSecretKey);
    }

    await outputFile.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    print('finished');
  }

  return path;
}
```

Comment: How can I just get the file path to the file in assets? I tried looking in the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`, but it's not there.

Comment: Even tried put it into `android/app/src/main/assets/`, and access using a `File` object and the Android `file:///android_asset/` url, but that just says file doesn't exist.. looks like my only option is write native code now..

Comment: Please, don't use outputFile.exists(). More info: https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_slow_async_io.html.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing work that is expensive and you don't want to block the UI, use the [`compute`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html) method from `package:flutter/foundation.dart`.  This will run the provided function in a separate isolate and return the results to you asynchronously.  `loadEncryptedPdf` must be a top level or static function to use it here though, and you are limited to passing one argument (but you can put them in a Map).

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

Future<String> loadEncryptedPdf(Map<String, String> arguments) async {
  // this runs on another isolate
  ...
} 

final String result = await compute(loadEncryptedPdf, {'fileName': /*.../*});
```

Comment: This results in a `Exception: Platform messages can only be sent from the main isolate`

Files can't be read from the assets using Isolates :(